# No Audio out in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, asus, hdmi

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed.  I cannot get my audio to work. I have hdmi output to Samsung TV.  Under sound settings I have Digital Ouput (S/PDIF) and Analog Output but neither give me the option for HDMI.

I'm removed alsa and pulseaudio and reinstalled. Tried alsamixer among some other things but nothing seems to help.  MOBO is M4A785td-m evo.

My sound card shows up in aplay but not in sound settings

```
$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 2: VT1708S HP [VT1708S HP]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

The Following fixed my problem.  My sound card was a radeon 4200 series.

It is also notable that the open source driver for ATI/AMD (called radeon), has experimental support for HDMI/DisplayPort audio, at least for some cards. It is disabled by default, but you can activate it by adding `radeon.audio=1` as a kernel boot parameter:

Run

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line so it includes `radeon.audio=1`, for example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
```

Run

```
sudo update-grub.
```

And reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer that you are looking for, but Ubuntu 12.10 is no longer supported.  It may be best to switch either to [12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or to [13.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Do you need 12.10 for some particular reason?

The next thing I would check is that you MOBO supports sound through HDMI connection and if you have some headphones, to try to get sound straight through the audio jack.  This at leasts tests that the sound card is working.  I am no sound expert with Ubuntu.

Comment: I miss spoke it is 12.04 and headphones work on the mobo. I had WIN 7 on it previously and hdmi works

Comment: I really wish I had more for you then.  Glad you figured it out though. Happier Ubuntu days ahead I'm sure.